# Task only runs once in Task Scheduler when trigger the task for the first time

Tags: windows-task-scheduler

I want to run a console application 'Download.exe' every 5 minutes. There is no problem in the Exe file I've created. The execution only happens when the first time I click the Run button. Anyone can help regarding this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

At the upper left corner, use "One time" instead of "Daily".

Comment: Ok. I've changed it to "One time". But now I realised one problem. I run the task for the first time, the status is "Running" now. I close the Task Scheduler and reopen it again, the status is "Ready" now. Does this means the scheduling fails?

Comment: "Ready" means it is ready for the next run. It is expected when the task is finished. You can check if the previous run was successful or failed in the "History" tab (first double click the task to bring up the Properties dialog).